# LaTeX math whitespace

Tags: math-mode, spacing, standalone

when I try to display a math equation with LaTeX, there is always whitespace to the right and left of the math equation. I am trying it with code like this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
%Math equation here
\end{document}
```

This method works for regular text, it just doesn't seem to work for math. Is there a solution?

Comment: Doesn't happen to me. May you give a real example?

Comment: It would be great if you could give a complete document that acts like this.  For example, what kind of "math equation" are you using?  `$...$`?  `\[...\]`?  `\begin{align}...\end{align}`?

Comment: @egreg: can easily been seen with `\[ y \]`

Comment: I only didn't post it because I didn't see it as relevant, but, here it is: `\documentclass{standalone` `\begin{document}` `\[ \int_1^a{\frac{dx}{x}} = \ln a \]` `\[ \int{x^n} = \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\]` `\end{document}`

Comment: The one work-around is to use [`pdfcrop`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfcrop), as suggested in my comment where [this original problem](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31054/whitespace-problems-with-dvipng-with-latex/31056#31056) arose. However, this may be related to some options of [`preview`](http://ctan.org/pkg/preview).

Comment: Oh, thank you, I didn't see that before I posted. With what program can I convert PDF to PNG?

Comment: @mebob: Under Unix/Linux, `convert <filename>.PDF <filename>.PNG` should do the trick. It uses [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php).

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I'm going with the solution suggested by egreg as it doesn't require as many external programs for conversion to PNG.

Comment: You could also use [`texrendr.com`](http://texrendr.com) for rendering LaTeX math as a picture. It also has a feature to upload your code to an image hoster.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The construction `\[...\]` builds a whole paragraph, so that **standalone** is forced to leave space for it.

A formula written as

```
$\displaystyle <formula>$
```

will give the same result as `\[<formula>\]`, but will not produce excess white space.

If you want two "centered" formulas one after the other, then

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\begin{gathered}
\int_1^a{\frac{dx}{x}} = \ln a \\
\int{x^n} = \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}
\end{gathered}$
\end{document}
```

is the way to go. For aligned equations you can use `aligned`.

Answer (score 7):

Based on the code in the comments this seems to have been an issue with how the `standalone` package is begin used.
With the latest version of `standalone`, the `[varwidth]` option is needed.
The MWE below does not produce any space around the formulas:

[image]

### Note:

- It is not normally a good idea to have to consecutive display mode equations without any text in between. See [Uneven vertical spacing displaymath](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28940/uneven-vertical-spacing-displaymath)

### Code:

```
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document} 
  \[ \int_1^a \frac{dx}{x} = \ln a \]
  \[ \int {x^n} = \frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}\] 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Re `varwidth`: The v1.0 version uses `crop` by default, not `preview` as before, and this uses a horizontal box for the content. The ``\[ \]`` doesn't like restricted horizontal mode. The `varwidth` options wraps the content into a `varwidth` environment (from the `varwidth` package) which is a `minipage` with a variable width. Unfortunately I had to sacrifice 100% backwards compatibility in order to provide a good default setting. `crop` avoids a few drawbacks of `preview`. The default setting can be easily changed using the config file. See the manual, especially the "Version update" section

Answer (score 3):

try

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\PreviewEnvironment{displaymath}
\begin{document}
\begin{displaymath}y=f(x)\end{displaymath}
\end{document}
```

it creates a file `<file>-pics.pdf` which holds the equation as a cropped pdf

Run it with `pdflatex -shell-escape <file>` or alternetively with `xelatex` or `lualatex`

Comment: I tried to typeset your code using TeXShop first, with XeLaTeX selected and second, with LuaLaTeX selected. However, in both cases, I get "!undefined control sequence. \PreviewEnvironment".