# How to increase the dpi without increasing the size of the picture via dvipng?

Tags: graphics, png, dvi

There is a useful tool in MikTeX called dvipng,  which can transform dvi file to png file.

My question is about the useage of this command.
I usually use it with options

> -T tight -D 120 -z 9 -bg Transparent

,

but sometimes pictures output are not clear enough when printed on papers,

[image]

so I increased the dpi to 1200 in order to make them more clear:

> -T tight -D 1200 -z 9 -bg Transparent

.

Despite of it goes more clear indeed, the size of the picture, out of my expectation, increased 99 times at the same time.

[image]

I want to increase the dpi without increasing the size of the picture, so how to realize it?

Comment: `dvipng` is not a MiKTeX tool, it is just included there as well as in TeX Live.

Comment: Could you explain what the goal of making PNG from DVI is? Then someone might suggest an alternative solution.

Comment: @amorua Okay, no problem. My goal is paste formulae as png into doc files, but I found 120dpi is not clear enough, 1200dpi is much better but needs to have a shrinking manually. So what I'm seeking is to make high quality pictures with standard size.

Comment: @Popopo Option 1: Retype in `.doc` with inbuilt math or mathtype incase of few equations   Option 2: Check 200/300 dpi png compromising quality over size(math in png is not recommended choice last resort).

Comment: somewhat related [Whitespace problems with DVIPNG with LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31054)

Comment: @Popopo: To add tex formula's as png into doc you may give this tool a try: http://sourceforge.net/projects/texsword/  It automates the process and keeps editable equations inside doc-file. It also allows numbering and referencing of equations.

Comment: @amorua It sounds good, but unfortunately incompatible with word 2013...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A short (non-technical) answer is: it is impossible to do with `dvipng`

A longer (technical) answer is: the problem is that `dvipng` does not include a so called pHYs chunk in the PNG file it makes. This chunk contains the information about the size (in meters) of the pixel.

So, if your vector image is 1in x 1in and you render it to PNG with an option "-D 120", you'll get an image with dimensions of 120 x 120 pixels and there'll be no further information about resolution included in the PNG file.

See also https://web.archive.org/web/20130512151707/http://list-archives.org/2012/10/14/dvipng-nongnu-org/does-dvipng-include-the-dpi-information-in-its-output/f/6630375274

Comment: Well...it sounds sadly to me. But anyway thanks to you.